# position: sticky not working in firefox

Tags: css, firefox, sticky

position:sticky is said to be working in firefox but I'm not seeing my sidebar stick.

My html looks like this:

```
<div class="wrap">

    <div class="sticky">side </div>    
    <div class="content">content <div>
<div>
```

My css:

```
.content{
    height: 2000px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.sticky{
    position: sticky;
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
}
```

As I scroll down the sidebar scrolls with the content. It doesn't stick. Anyone know what could be the issue?

Comment: What FireFox version?

Comment: I have the latest version

Comment: As of Feb 2018 `position: sticky` for `th` still doesn't work in FF `58.0 (64-bit)`. Three years behind!

Comment: Yep it still doesn't work on thead and tr elements in ff chrome opera and maybe more browsers

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It sticks if you specify a `top` value:

```
.sticky{
   position: -webkit-sticky; /* for safari */
   position: sticky;
   width: 200px;
   float: left;
   top: 10px;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3qoe0wd0/)

Comment: This doesn't work when you put the sticky thing below something else: https://jsfiddle.net/3qoe0wd0/44/ I'm using Firefox 50.1.0

Comment: @ChrisSmith The html markup is broken in your fiddle. That is likely an issue. The div tag isn't closed on the content class.

Answer (score 17):

I have the same issue in 2020 - this post pops up first in google but none of the answers helped me.

The actual problem was that sticky doesn't play well with the parent element being **display: flex**.

References:
  - [position: sticky, works in Chrome but not in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52137323/position-sticky-works-in-chrome-but-not-in-firefox/52137686)
  - https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1488080

Comment: I'm so bummed that this bug hasn't been fixed yet.  I guess it's low priority but it breaks my app's layout in Firefox.

Comment: same issue in a display:grid element. Works like a dream on Chrome, scrolls right through my footer in firefox and then doesnt stick on the way up :(

Comment: @LaZza Using display:block for sticky element helped me solve the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

Position sticky also don't work if the parent element is set to overflow: hidden because it can't calculate the height correctly.

Comment: It will not work with overflow-x: hidden as well.  So, any overflow (e.g. overflow, overflow-y, overflow-x) will bug out sticky.

Answer (score 1):

`position: sticky` does not work on table elements such as `tr` as well as some others.

A workaround is to wrap whatever you want sticky inside a `span` element.

```
    <style>.sticky span {position: -webkit-sticky; position: sticky; top: 0;}</style> 
    <td class='sticky' valign='top' width='200'>
    <span>
        (table contents)
    </span>
    </td>
```

[Related answers and solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44001954/css-only-sticky-table-headers-in-chrome)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix it by using 'display: table-cell'.

My problem concerned a thead that didn't want to stick anymore on Firefox as soon as I fixed the same problem in Chrome by using display: block or inline-block.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, even though I set a top value, the sticky element would not stick. The solution was to set a value also for height...

Answer (score 0):

```
.sticky-top {
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    z-index: 1020;
    top: 86px;
    height: min-content;
}
```

Adding **height: min-content;** fixed my issue on firefox

Answer (score 0):

To anyone still having this trouble:

> Firefox uses the parent display as a rendering condition

So try making the child `display: inline` and parent `display: inline`

Remember that you still need to check the parent position and size for all browsers.
Sticky is great but it is very case-specific use.

Answer (score 0):

I found the alt way with very simple but works.

```
position:fixed;
width:100%;
top:0;
z-index:1; /*depends on your elements*/
```

Work on every browsers, no bulls. If your topnav has a lot of elements, the sticky wil not working, I beleive it's because of some `overflow:hidden;`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the sticky element was taking a `display: table;` property, which when I changed to `display: block;`, the sticky was fixed in Firefox. So, have a look at the display property before considering other fixes.

Answer (score 0):

Just stumbled on this so it seems to still be an issue in 2022. I'll leave here what I had that allowed me to clearly replicate the OP and what I added to mitigate it.

```
div {
  position: sticky;
- display: inline;
+ display: block;
+ height: 100px;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Try the following on the parent component:

```
transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0); 
overflow: inherit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey this could be a shot in the dark, but i just fixed this bug on my code, turns out i was setting a height of 100vh to my body element, my body element in this case is a section with id=body.

in the css file i put a height of 100vh for #body element, but turns out the sticky position type did not like that and only worked once i removed it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).