# How to freeze header of nested/complex table in HTML

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am having below complex/nested HTML Table (I am developing Asp.net mvc application) as,

[Table where I want to freeze header (click to view)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYU4j.jpg)

I want to freeze the header for this table on scrolling.

As table contains odd even number of of columns in header and table body, I cant apply datatables on given column.
I tried jquery code also but it didn't work.

Please suggest me how I can freeze this table header or is there any other way that I can use to implement this kind of table.

This kind of table is possible using Kendo grid ui?

Please suggest,

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

I hope one of these following would help on your requirements.

[How to stick table header(thead) on top while scrolling down the table rows with fixed header(navbar) in bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24840074/how-to-stick-table-headerthead-on-top-while-scrolling-down-the-table-rows-with)

[CSS-Only Sticky Table Headers In Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44001954/css-only-sticky-table-headers-in-chrome)

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks but I have seen this.
This is not what I exactly want.