# Sticky Table two header using CSS for all OS

Tags: html, css

i have two table headers and i want to sticky it using CSS only. Here is my html, and also posted image of my table, i have all the dynamic data and columns.

```
       <div class="fix-table-parent">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr class="first_head">
                    <th>test11</th>
                    <th>test12</th>
                    <th>test13</th>
                </tr>
                <tr class="second_head">
                    <th>test21</th>
                    <th>test22</th>
                    <th>test23</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>data1</td>
                    <td>data2</td>
                    <td>data3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>data1</td>
                    <td>data2</td>
                    <td>data3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>data1</td>
                    <td>data2</td>
                    <td>data3</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

[image]

> How can I make the headers sticky using only CSS?

Comment: Can you elaborate on your question a little bit? Is your data static? How much data do you have to show and how many columns are there?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS-Only Sticky Table Headers In Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44001954/css-only-sticky-table-headers-in-chrome)

Comment: @DhavalChheda my data and columns both are dynamic, and i posted one image of my table

Comment: Oh ohk I get it, It is bit tricky since you cannot find any libraries that will do that. I had done that before but don't have the code, if it is alright with you I can give you an idea in the answer section.

Comment: @DhavalChheda yes please.

Comment: You can create two similiar tables and superimpose on each other. For the top table set the visibility of data to hidden and for the behind table, set the z-index of header to maximum and the visibility of other data to hidden. So when u do this, the header of behind table which is static will always be present there but the data will be shown from the top table so you can scroll down.

Answer (score 3):

Try below `css`. You have to change `top: 20px;` with height of `.first_head`.

```
.fix-table-paren thead .first_head th{ position: sticky; top: 0; }
.fix-table-paren thead .second_head th{ position: sticky; top: 20px; }
```

Comment: it's working fine but in my case some time **i have only one header** so in that case it was no working, and i can not put static **top: 20px**