# Stylish style to float the table header after it's been scrolled on top

Tags: html, css, stylish

I'm trying to write myself a little Stylish style for one page, for easier reading.
The page in question is https://satisfactory.fandom.com/wiki/Hard_Drive.
What I want to achieve is to the top row of this table (with "alternate name", "product" and so on) [image]
to behave similar to the top wikia navbar - I want it to be on it's place, until it's been scrolled past down, then to stay at the top - sort of as freezing a row in a spreadsheet.

The `position: sticky;` should do what I want, but nothing changes. I've tried with `background-color` to see if I'm targeting the proper element, and the background color changed.

Here's how I'm trying to do it

```css
table#alternateRecipesTable th {
    position:sticky!important;
    top: 0px!important;
}
```

I'm using firefox 100 with stylus 1.5.21.

Thank you.

Comment: Although I don't belive it answers your question, there is some discussion of this in a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44001954/css-only-sticky-table-headers-in-chrome that might help you modify your implementation to one that works. If you can't get a suitable table style to apply sticky as you need, have you considered instead emulating a table with css grid layout?

Answer (score 1):

Your plan to set the `position: sticky` CSS property is correct. However, to work this as expected, there can't be a parent element with `overflow: hidden`.

If you set the `position: sticky` to your head cells of the table, you also need to check every parent element and unset the `overflow: hidden` property, otherwise it will not work.

Comment: Thanks, setting `overflow-x:visible!important;` worked. I tried to apply it to something specified, but setting it to everything (*) seems to not break anything and works just like I wanted. Thank you.